# how to find most frequent values in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I want to find frequent values in a list using `collections.Counter`. Here is an example list:

```py
from collections import Counter

lastNodes = ['138885662','192562407','192562407','138885662','121332964','185592680','144024400','144024400','144024400','138885662']
c = Counter(lastNodes)
```

output of `print(c)`:

```
Counter({'121332964': 1,
         '138885662': 3,
         '144024400': 3,
         '185592680': 1,
         '192562407': 2})
```

I used `c.most_common(1)` to get the most frequent value, which output `[('138885662', 3)]`.

but I want to get values which have 3 times repeated in the list. desired output:

```
[('138885662', 3), ('144024400', 3)]
```

and what if I want those which have 3 and 2 repeated values:

```
[('138885662', 3), ('144024400', 3), ('192562407', 2)]
```

of course this is an example list. I have an algorithm which generates dynamic lists. so I don't know how many most frequent values exist in every list

Comment: where does the `Counter` class come from?

Comment: If you omit the argument to `most_common`, it will return a sorted list of *all* of the counts.  That might be the best thing for this.  You would need to decide how many of the entries you want to use.

Comment: @jemand771 It's part of `collections`, which is a standard Python library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With itertools:

```
from itertools import chain, islice, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

n = 2

# group the items having same count together
grouped = (list(group) for _, group in groupby(c.most_common(), key=itemgetter(1)))

# slice first `n` of them
top_n = islice(grouped, n)

# flatten
result = list(chain.from_iterable(top_n))
```

where `itemgetter(1)` helps grouping items of counter according to their frequencies (in tuples, 0th entry is item itself, 1st entry is its count so we use 1; also noting that `groupby` expects a sorted data which `most_common` provides).

sample runs:

```
# for n = 1
[("138885662", 3), ("144024400", 3)]

# for n = 2
[("138885662", 3), ("144024400", 3), ("192562407", 2)]

# for n = 3
[("138885662", 3), ("144024400", 3), ("192562407", 2), ("121332964", 1), ("185592680", 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take 2 of them in `most_common`:

```py
>>> c.most_common(2)
[('138885662', 3), ('144024400', 3)]
```

Comment: if I want to use 2 I want to get 2 different frequent. I mean desired output should be: [('138885662', 3), ('144024400', 3) ,('192562407', 2)]

Comment: @saharrezazadeh, can you change your desire output then? because that matches exactly what you were asking :)

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is loop through the list and use the count function and if the number of occurences of that element is 3 append it to another list and

````
lst = []
for i in lastNodes:
    if lastNodes.count(i) == 3:
        lst.append(i)```
````

Comment: you should probably use a set to avoid having duplicates in your output list. either make `lst` a set or do `for i in set(lastNodes):`